# Picture being uploaded to Firebase storage using PHP but have to create access token manually to make it visible

Tags: php, google-cloud-storage, firebase-storage

I am using PHP to upload image to firebase storage. the picture is being uploaded but it is not being accessible as i have to manually create " access token " to make it accessible.
here is the code im using

```
 $bucketName = "example.appspot.com";
$objectName = 'Photos/test.jpeg';
$storage = new StorageClient();
$bucket = $storage->bucket($bucketName);
$object = $bucket->upload(fopen('sign.jpeg', 'r'),
    [
       'name' => $objectName
    
    ]
    
 );
```

Comment: You can access it by using making a download url.

Answer (score 2):

That is indeed working as expected: since your upload is not going through a Firebase SDK, there is not method to generate a download URL.

The common workaround is to [create a signed URL](http://googleapis.github.io/google-cloud-php/#/docs/cloud-storage/v1.22.0/storage/storageobject?method=signedUrl) with an expiration time far into the future, which is the closest equivalent  that Cloud Storage has to Firebase's download URL.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to [@Frank](https://stackoverflow.com/users/209103/frank-van-puffelen)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63548203/284325), you could also assign the `publicRead` ACL to the uploaded file and compose the public URL manually:

```php
$bucketName = "example.appspot.com";
$objectName = 'Photos/test.jpeg';

$storage = new StorageClient();
$bucket = $storage->bucket($bucketName);

$object = $bucket->upload(fopen('sign.jpeg', 'r'), [
   'name' => $objectName
   'predefinedAcl' => 'publicRead'
]);

$publicUrl = "https://{$bucket->name()}.storage.googleapis.com/{$object->name()}";
```

Answer (score 1):

I have made an indirect way to generate and store the access token.

```
$payload = file_get_contents('https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/example.appspot.com/o/Photos%2Fpic.jpeg');
$data = json_decode($payload); 
echo $data->downloadTokens;
```

This code has created the access token and it shows the downloadToken on screen.

Thank you everyone for your answers.