# Laravel - How to add image file to Firebase cloud storage?

Tags: php, laravel, firebase, eloquent, google-cloud-storage

How do I upload images to firebase cloud storage? The documentation gives only these methodes but no upload method. This is the documentation link https://firebase-php.readthedocs.io/en/stable/cloud-storage.html

```
$storage = $factory->createStorage();
$storageClient = $storage->getStorageClient();
$defaultBucket = $storage->getBucket();
```

I have seen another stack question related but don't understand the answer.
I would also like to get a link to the stored file.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check official firebase [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/upload-files), as is mentioned there:

"**To upload a file to Cloud Storage, you first create a reference to the full path of the file, including the file name.**"

For example:

```
// Create a root reference
var storageRef = firebase.storage().ref();

// Create a reference to 'mountains.jpg'
var mountainsRef = storageRef.child('mountains.jpg');

// Create a reference to 'images/mountains.jpg'
var mountainImagesRef = storageRef.child('images/mountains.jpg');

// While the file names are the same, the references point to different files
mountainsRef.name === mountainImagesRef.name            // true
mountainsRef.fullPath === mountainImagesRef.fullPath    // false
```

Also, I found another thread [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63546484/picture-being-uploaded-to-firebase-storage-using-php-but-have-to-create-access-t) where you can find an example using php

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this,

```
$storage = new StorageClient();
$file = fopen($source, 'r');
$bucket = $storage->bucket($bucketName);
$object = $bucket->upload($file, [
    'name' => $objectName
]);
printf('Uploaded %s to gs://%s/%s' . PHP_EOL, basename($source), $bucketName, $objectName);
```

There examples on gcp github repository.

- file upload example : [here](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/php-docs-samples/blob/master/storage/src/upload_object.php)
- other examples: [here](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/php-docs-samples/tree/master/storage/src)

Comment: kreait/firebase-php provides a bridge to google/cloud-storage, so: yes, it does, you should try :)

Comment: You can find an example implementation at https://github.com/jeromegamez/firebase-php-examples/blob/main/src/Command/UploadFileCommand.php